# using indexOf on array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

Currently I have an array of objects and I want to check if an object exists in the array. My method:

```
findUser(user: UserModel) {
    let userToRemove = this.directory.users.indexOf(user);
    if(userToRemove) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Build error is: `Property 'indexOf' does not exist on type 'UserModel'.`
When I debug through my console I am able to use the same syntax to return user.
I tried: 
`let userToRemove = Array(this.directory.users).indexOf(user);`

It builds but then it never finds the user even though I know the user exists.

Comment: You have likely mistyped your interfaces but have not included the relevant code.  Without a [mcve] all we can do is guess.  My guess is that you have something like `interface Directory { users: UserModel }` where you should have `interface Directory { users: Array<UserModel> }`.

Comment: @PranavCBalan it is an array

Comment: It’s not typed properly to an array where it’s defined, and indexOf with objects uses object references to locate items. If it isn’t the same object reference it won’t find it. Try using .find() instead and use some identifying property to match (like an id)

Comment: What is the result of the `indexOf` function? If it's zero (i.e. first element of the array), the `if` condition will return false, as zero is a falsy value. Additionally, `indexOf` returns -1 for element that does not exist in the array, but -1 is a truthy value.

Comment: @jcalz that was it. i had `users: UserModel` so i updated it to `users: UserModel[] = []` and it worked as expected. Thanks!